# Cannot insert value for identity when Identitt_insert is set to OFF

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, identity

I'm aware that I'm not the first to ask this question here. But after going through a LOT of answers about this, I still cannot fix my issue.

So here it is.

I have multiple derived models in my Code First model, sharing the same Idenity property.

**Here is an  example of my models**

```
public class Foo 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty{get;set;}
}

public class DerivedFoo : Foo
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty {get;set;}
}

public class EvenMordeDerivedFoo : DerivedFoo 
{
    public string AndAnotherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

So from my understanding my **FooContext** override should look like this :

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Foo> Foos{get;set;}
   public DbSet<DerivedFoo> DerivedFoos{get;set;}
   public DbSet<EvenMordeDerivedFoo > EvenMordeDerivedFoos{get;set;}

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DerivedFoo>().ToTable("DerivedFoo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<EvenMordeDerivedFoo >().ToTable("EvenMordeDerivedFoo ");
    }
}
```

With this, I can create and run context.SaveChanges() with Foo without any problem. But when i try to create a DerivedFoo via:

```
var derivedFoo= _context.DerivedFoos.Create();
_context.DerivedFoos.Add(derivedFoo);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I end up with the infamous error :

> "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'DerivedFoo' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

From my understanding, Entity Framework is trying to explain that I shouldn't being modifying the porperty FooId by myself if I set Identity_Insert to true.

I agree with EF on this, because I want this FooId property to set itself every time I create a new Foo, DerivedFoo or EvenMordeDerivedFoo, this explaining why I added the line

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

So if anyone could explain what i did wrong could explain, that would be very nice.

Edit : I still can't find an answer, and after verification, my model mostly match [this tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) model. So I'm pretty sure the answer is quite simple, but I fail to find what I missed

Comment: Is the database schema generated with migration from the above model (TPT as I see). If yes, the `FooId` columns in `DerivedFoo`, `EvenMordeDerivedFoo` etc. should **not** be identity.

Comment: Yep the database is generated from the model. So if I get you right, I should add some ID properties in DerivedFoo and EvenMoreDerivedFoo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I should add some ID properties in DerivedFoo and EvenMoreDerivedFoo

No.  The Entities are fine.  The tables for the derived types need to not have IDENTITY property.

EG, this will create tables where only Foo's ID column has the IDENTITY property:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    public class Foo
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int FooId { get; set; }

        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedFoo : Foo
    {
        public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class EvenMordeDerivedFoo : DerivedFoo
    {
        public string AndAnotherProperty { get; set; }
    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DerivedFoo> DerivedFoos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EvenMordeDerivedFoo> EvenMordeDerivedFoos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DerivedFoo>().ToTable("DerivedFoo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<EvenMordeDerivedFoo>().ToTable("EvenMordeDerivedFoo ");
        }
    }




    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                db.Database.Initialize(true);

                var derivedFoo = db.DerivedFoos.Create();
                db.DerivedFoos.Add(derivedFoo);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine ! I'm not sure where I failed because I'm almost sure to have tried implementing it this way at some point, maybe I didn't updated my database correctly.
Thanks a lot !